# Protractor : Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined. If i create new object of PageObject

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to create a object of page object into spec and i am getting the error.

**dashboard.pageObject.js**

```
/*global exports,console*/

module.exports = function(){

    this.dashboarurl = 'http://localhost:2525/ars-webapp/';    

        this.createNewReport_Clickhear = element(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Click Here')]"));
        this.reportInputModel = element(by.model('reportDefCntrl.reportDef.reportname'));
        this.reportDescriptionModel = element(by.model('reportDefCntrl.reportDef.reportdesc'));     
        this.templateListSelect = element(By.xpath("//select[@id='template-list-select']")).click();
        this.selectAlarmDashboarTemplate= element(By.xpath("//option[contains(@value,'number:2')]"));
        this.durationOfAlarmTemplate = element(By.xpath("//span[@class='ui-select-placeholder text-muted ng-binding']"));
        this.duration_Daily = element(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Daily')]"));
        this.addObject = element(By.xpath("//button[@data-ng-click='reportDefCntrl.addLogObjects()']"));
        this.searchInput = element(By.xpath("//input[@type='search']"));
        this.searchButton = element(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Search')]"));
        this.selectAllButton = element(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'SelectAll')]"));
        this.addObjectButton = element(By.xpath("//button[@data-ng-click='addLogObjectsCntrl.submitObjects()']"));
        this.saveButton = element(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Save')]"));

}
```

**Specfile is**

/*global require,console*/

```
var Dashboard = require('../pageObjects/dashboard.pageObject.js');

var dashboard = new Dashboard();

describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', function() {
    browser.get(dashboard.dashboarurl);
    }
```

if i skip the line

```
var dashboard = new Dashboard();
```

and provide

```
 browser.get('http://localhost:2525/ars-webapp/');
```

instead of

```
browser.get(dashboard.dashboarurl);
```

it's working .
but i can't use feature of page object.

if i use

```
var dashboard = new Dashboard();
```

so i am getting error

> E/launcher - Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page:
>   "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a
>   non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation,
>   which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See
>   http://git.io/v4gXM for details"

Comment: Is the page you are trying to test angular? If not you cannot use 'browser.get()'

Comment: yes this page is angular page. but why i can't initialize the object new Dashboard();

Answer (score 0):

Oh Man .. found it !!.. Everything was fine in your code. You know what .. The problem was .. you had a `click()` in this line `this.templateListSelect = element(By.xpath("")).click()` in your file - `dashboard.pageObject.js`

Since you have a `require()` first .. The dashboard file is executed first and `click()` is trigerred even before `browser.get()` and thats the reason you were seeing that error